# how reuse word 2007 content control value

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm creating Microsoft word 2007 template document. My document too many repeating some text in document. I need to insert duplicated text once. I'm inserting text content control in document and named. But how can't use this content control value in other section.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=363544

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Repeating_Data.htm